# Specifying project configuration for Azure continuous deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, kudu

I have setup continuous deployment for a Azure Web App from a Bitbucket repository. This is working fine. The Release project configuration is used to deploy the web app on Azure.

How can I specify that a custom project configuration should be used while doing the continuous deployment. E.g. in my case I have created a new configuration -"Dev".

Answer (score 2):

[Project Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) to the rescue.

Add a .deployment file to the repository with the following configuration:

```
[config]
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:Configuration=Dev
```

The full description of what you can do with Kudo, which is built into Azure can be accessed here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings

For verifying the correct msbuild settings were picked up you can access the Activity Logs under the Deployment Details blade on the Azure portal.